# Automapper - Conditional mapping breaks IncludeMembers configuration

Tags: automapper

Strait to the problem from the title.

I have the following models configured:

```
internal class TaskPathViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public int PathId { get; set; }
}

internal class TaskViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TaskPathViewModel Path { get; set; }
}

internal class ProjectTask
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; } 

    public int PathId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map TaskViewModel onto ProjectTask. My mapping profile configuration is:

```
internal class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TaskViewModel, ProjectTask>()
            .ForMember(p => p.TaskId, p => p.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
            .IncludeMembers(m => m.Path)
            .ForMember(p => p.PathId, p => p.Condition(s => s.Path != null))
            .ForMember(p => p.ProjectId, p => p.Condition(s => s.Path != null))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<TaskPathViewModel, ProjectTask>()
            .ForMember(p => p.PathId, s => s.MapFrom(p => p.PathId))
            .ForMember(p => p.ProjectId, s => s.MapFrom(p => p.ProjectId))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Here I use IncludeMembers to map Path property (TaskPathViewModel) onto ProjectId and PathId properties from the ProjectTask class.

If I remove Conditions it works fine but with the conditions in place it doesn't and just return properties with default values (0 for integers).

Here is the entry point with the Map call:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
    }));

    var task = new TaskViewModel
    {
        Id = 1,
        Path = new TaskPathViewModel
        {
            PathId = 2,
            ProjectId = 3
        }
    };

    var map = mapper.Map<ProjectTask>(task);
}
```

The expected behavior is that whenever the Path property is set the ProjectId and PathId properties get mapped. If Path is null then those two properties left unset. In the example below the ProjectId and PathId are always 0 (zero) while I'd expect them to have values 3 and 2 respectively.

We use this technique a lot for the PATCH methods in our API which allows us supply only certain properties which a client wants to update. It works fine on simple properties and collections but it fails to work with IncludeMembers.

What have I missed? Any help very appreciated!

Comment: That's not possible. Once you configure a member in the main map, `IncludeMembers` doesn't apply anymore. But if `Path` is `null`,  ProjectId and PathId will be zero, so why bother with the condition?

Comment: I've showed a bit simplified example. In the real world we get entities from our DAL and map view models onto them. I.e. var taskFromDal = _taskRepository.GetTask(); mapper.Map(taskFromDal, taskViewModel); This should ensure that properties which are not populated on taskViewModel will be preserved from the original taskFromDal. In this case, of course we need nullable properties on taskViewModel. I decided not to overcomplicate the example. Also I should have been mentioned that I use Automapper v10.1.1